# How to select List in Room by value in Entity?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

So, I have this DAO, and I want select List of Cams by field cityName. The problem is, if I set in loop for each cam in List city name, how I take List from table by this field?

```
@Dao
public interface CamDAO {

    @Insert
    void insert(List <Cam> cams);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cam WHERE cityName IS :cityName")
    List <Cam> selectByName(String cityName) throws IOException;
}
```

And I have Entity Cam, and cityName is field in cam.

```
@Entity
public class Cam {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String cityName;
    private String title;
    @TypeConverters(BitmapConverter.class)
    private Bitmap bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM cam  WHERE cityName =:cityName;
```